# Return string or object which funtion type is Task<ReplaceOneResult>

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am new in mongoDB, and try to make an CRUD operation in asp.net core. I have a function in Repository class and it's return type is Task.

Code :

```
    public async Task<ReplaceOneResult> UpdateBusinessUnit(string id, BusinessUnit businessUnit)
    {
       try
       {
            return await _context.BusinessUnits.ReplaceOneAsync(doc => doc.Id == id, businessUnit);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            businessUnit = new BusinessUnit();
            businessUnit.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            return null; //Problem here
       }
    }
```

I want to return an Object or string in catch part. How can I do it or any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you just return an object `new ReplaceOneResult();`? the async keyword before your method definition will wrap it into a task

Comment: by the way, this (multi thread) task call in web page is pointless ! and probably make longer time than a normal call.

Comment: @Aristos bro, its a part of an web api.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `object` or `string`, because your method must return `ReplaceOneResult`. You need either change return type of method, or add properties like `Success` or `MessageText` to `ReplaceOneResult` and return `ReplaceOneResult` instance.